# not selector in css not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is the code I have tried

**HTML**

```
<div>
     <span>Span1</span>
     <span>Span12</span>
     <span>Span13</span>
</div> 

<div>
     <span>Span1</span>
     <span>Span12</span>
     <span>Span13</span>
</div> 

<span>Span2</span> 
<span>Span3</span>
```

**CSS**

```
 :not(div>span)
   {
      color : #ff0000;
   }
```

I want the spans with `span2` and `span3` to be red using **not selector**

Check the Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/82KwV/

Comment: What about span12 and 13?

Comment: Are you sure [this](http://jsfiddle.net/82KwV/2/) is what you want?

Comment: @Moob i know other ways to get this solution but i would like to know ho i can get using not selector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`:not`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) accepts a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) as an argument. `div > span` is not a simple selector, so it cannot be used in that context. As a result, you can't say "I want everything that is not a span with a div parent to be red" in CSS and you have to compromise.

One possibility is to target specific subsets of the general case. For example the subtly different "all spans that do not have a div parent" corresponds to:

```
:not(div) > span { color: red }
```

In more complicated scenarios this approach might not be feasible (e.g. you cannot use `div, p` instead of `div` above), in which case you would have to turn to other options such as the "do/undo" trick:

```
span { color: red }
div > span { color: inherit }
```

This arrangement can easily be expanded to `p > span, div > span`, but of course there is a tradeoff: these rules might override something else in your stylesheets.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴜnBᴇrtiL: I have given workarounds above. There is no way to do exactly what your hypothetical selector does. CSS does not work that way, and it will not work for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

`:not` doesn't allow this type of selector. Better use

```
body > span { color: red }
```

This is cleaner than patching it together using multiple rules.

Comment: It may be cleaner *now*, but it doesn't do the same thing. You can easily see that in a more complicated page, or in more complicated instances of this scenario, you would have to write a lot of selectors to target everything. That also makes the solution very brittle: change the structure a little (e.g. put a `p` around the spans) and it doesn't work anymore. These are also factors that one should take into account.

Comment: @Jon: You are right, but it's always cleaner to select using a single rule. Using "undo" selectors breaks as well, even using `color: inherit`, as this may override another setting. You simply can not disable a particular CSS setting (speaking of a "line of code") for specific subsets in CSS.

Comment: My point is that the two approaches don't do the same thing. If one cares about the difference one way or another then it doesn't matter which one is cleaner, because only one would work.

Comment: @Jon: My point is that CSS has only set union at the tagname selector level, not set exclusion. `color: inherit` does not work as a context-insensitive "undo" solution, so only **n**one would work, but the single-selector solution can always be patched by adding more elements, while the multi-selector version requires copying of the exact rules from the surrounding context (which is code duplication, and might be infeasable)

Comment: Requiring your selectors to follow the markup exactly (vs only mentioning the structural elements that are of strategic interest) is also effectively duplication, and IMHO of a worse kind. *Any* compromise here (including both your and my suggestions) will have possibly significant drawbacks, so let's all be frank in admitting that.