# :not selector in css is not applied

Tags: html, css

I have a similar markup in my `html`:

```
<div class="...">
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="...">
    <input type="text" name="...">
    ...
    <div class="...">
        <a href="...">...</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="...">
        <input type="text" name="...">
    </div>
    <div class="...">
        <a href="...">...</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="...">
        <input type="hidden" name="...">
        <input type="text" name="...">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="...">
    <input type="text" name="...">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="..."> 
    <div class="...">
        <a href="...">...</a>
        ...
        <input type="text" name="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to assign `css` style **only** to `input[type='text']` elements that is inside a `div` element that is also a **sibling** of at least one `a`(anchor) element. So I use these `css` selector:

```
div > a ~ :not(input[type='hidden']) { /* css style */ }
div > a ~ input:not(input[type='hidden']) { /* css style */ }
div > a ~ input[type!='hidden'] { /* css style */ }
```

But it doesn't select anything. I've red [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835969/not-selector-in-css-not-working) that the `:not` selector cannot handle complex selections so I removed the `[type='hidden']` part of it, though it still doesn't work.

I manage to do some work-around like:

- Add `class` to all `input[type='text']` targets.
- Use this selector: `div > input[type='text']`

But if you can give me the selector for my requirements, I would be most grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your css selector to this instead:

```
div > a ~ :not([type='hidden']) { background: #000 }
```

**Update**: to select only the input fields

```
div > a ~ input:not([type='hidden']) { background: #000 }
```

Comment: Sir what if the `input` sibling comes _before_ the `anchor` element? then the `~` selector will be ineffective, is it not?

Comment: @gideon yes it wouldn't work. You get rid of `> a ~` to make it work.

Comment: Is there no selector for this situation:
`select all not hidden input field that are children of a div and` _younger_ `and` _older_ `sibling(s) of an anchor plus don't include these not hidden input fields that are children of div's if they don't have a anchor siblings`?

Answer (score 1):

you could give the text inputs a `class`, that would be the easiest solution, but i'am thinking that this is not an option based on the fact you are asking this question.

This are some selectors you could use:

```
.classname {}
div > a ~ input:not([type='hidden']) {}
```

or as you mentioned, a `class` to your `hidden`, that would give you this selector:

```
div > a ~ input:not(.classhiddeninputs) {}
```

Or in the case you know the exact location (meaning, the text input is always the 3th), you could do this:

```
div input:nth-of-type(3) {}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is one of my work around, though I belive there is a proper approach through `css` for this.